# GWT CellTable: Selecting one checkbox selects every checkbox/row in the table

Tags: javascript, java, gwt

I have a very basic CellTable in GWT right now and use a majority of the code shown [here](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable).

However when I toggle a checkbox, every single row gets highlighted.

Preview: [gfycat](https://gfycat.com/illegalpossibledrongo)

I did try so far:

- Multi-/SingleSelectionMode: (I only want to get one row, so I would prefer SingleSelectionMode)
- CheckBoxCell(true, true): -> This is exactly how I want the CellTable to look, however with these parameters I can't get an object with "getSelectedObject()". Other variations of the parameters(false,false/true, false) also didn't seem to work

```
    CellTable<Article> ArticleCt = new CellTable<Article>(KEY_PROVIDER); 

    ListHandler<Article> sortHandler = new ListHandler<Article>(Articles);
    ArticleCt.addColumnSortHandler(sortHandler);

    final MultiSelectionModel<Article> selectionModel1 = new MultiSelectionModel<Article>(KEY_PROVIDER);

    ArticleCt.setSelectionModel(selectionModel1, DefaultSelectionEventManager.<Article> createCheckboxManager());

    Column<Article, Boolean> checkColumn = new Column<Article, Boolean>(
                  new CheckboxCell(true, false)) {

      public Boolean getValue(Article object) {

      return selectionModel1.isSelected(object);
    }
    };
```

I want to have only the row with the checked checkbox selected so I can fetch the peticular row/object with `selectionMode.getSelectedObject()` or `selectionMode.getSelectedSet()`.

However every single row gets highlighted.

Comment: What is in your keyprovider? If keys are not unique, selection won't be able to tell the rows apart. Probably also want to pass the column index to `DefaultSelectionEventManager.createCheckboxManager()`.

Comment: Thank you soo much! Adding a simple increment key solved the problem. It worked even using without the index for the CheckboxManager, but I added it nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key provider, `KEY_PROVIDER` in the question above, must provide unique and consistent keys per row. For example, each row might have an "ID" field.

If more than one row shares a key, then selecting one seems to be the same to the selection model as selecting both. If a row's key is not consistent, then when a row is selected, it can't be queried later since its key changed.